# Unity fires "User cancelled login" everytime

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine

I am planning to use Facebook login for the WEBGL version of my game.

Everytime i try to login i recieve "User cancelled login",

My application is public and Settings -> Advanced -> Client OAuth Settings -  all are enabled

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Facebook.Unity;

public class FaceLogin : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Awake()
    {
        if (!FB.IsInitialized)
        {
            // Initialize the Facebook SDK
            FB.Init(InitCallback, OnHideUnity);
        }
        else
        {
            // Already initialized, signal an app activation App Event
            FB.ActivateApp();
        }
    }

    private void InitCallback()
    {
        if (FB.IsInitialized)
        {
            // Signal an app activation App Event
            FB.ActivateApp();
            // Continue with Facebook SDK
            // ...
            if (!FB.IsLoggedIn)
            {
                var perms = new List<string> {"public_profile", "email", "user_friends"};
                FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(perms, AuthCallback);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Failed to Initialize the Facebook SDK");
        }
    }

    private void OnHideUnity(bool isGameShown)
    {
        Time.timeScale = !isGameShown ? 0 : 1;
    }

    private void AuthCallback(ILoginResult result)
    {
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            // AccessToken class will have session details
            var aToken = AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
            // Print current access token's User ID
            Debug.Log(aToken.UserId);
            // Print current access token's granted permissions
            foreach (string perm in aToken.Permissions)
            {
                Debug.Log(perm);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("User cancelled login");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to login with some delay or on button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, Facebook allow apps to use unity facebook sdk only for 'android', 'ios' and 'facebook canvas app'. I used facebook sdk for android and canvas. In android, you should use some hashes for debug and release mode for security.

And in canvas (it supports unity web player, webgl etc.), facebook allows logins only as facebook canvas application ( even in development, debug mode ). So if your app is not a facebook canvas app, you cannot login.